# Testing default state for Angularjs ui-Router in karma-mocha

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, angular-ui-router, sinon, karma-mocha

I want to write test a in karma for checking default state. How can I set a wrong URL for UI-Router?

JS file:

```
app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');

$stateProvider
    .state('home', {
        url: '/home',
        templateUrl: 'home.html'
    });
});
```

Tests:

```
describe('UI-Route configuration', function() {

beforeEach(module('App'));

it('should load the home page.', inject(function($state) {
    var state = $state.get('home');
    assert.isDefined(state.templateUrl);
    expect(state.templateUrl).to.equal('home.html');
}));

it('should load the home page when other path', inject(function($state) {
    //something to write here, setting wrong url
}));
})
```

Please help me.

Comment: Can you show what you have tried so far? Having some code in your question will surely get you more attention and answers.

Comment: Thanks, I added sample of code.